# Alterando CSS com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

No meu select tenho a lista com as opções, ao selecionar uma opção o conteúdo se alterna pois é amarrado aos selects.

Quando coloco **data-native-menu="false"** o select não permite alterar o conteúdo da tabela e ao selecionar outra opção a tela não altera.

```
<select id="cities" style="padding: 5px; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 5px; height: 100%;" class="empty" name="cities" data-native-menu="false" onclick="selected(this.value)" >
   <option value="Selecionar">Selecionar</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var select = document.getElementById('cities');

    function selected(value){

    var dadosLoja = document.getElementsByClassName('dadosLoja');
        if(value != "Selecionar"){
            dadosLoja[0].style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            dadosLoja[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Estou utilizando o

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ao utilizar o data-native-menu="false" tive que alterar o onclick para onchange, ai funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Ao utilizar o **`data-native-menu="false"`** tive que alterar o **`onclick`** para **`onchange`**, ai funcionou!